# need a 3-group with 3 generators

Tags: gap, p-groups

I need a $3$-group of nilpotency class $3$ with $3$ generators, but I can't find any group meeting these criteria. Does such a group exist?

I've already used GAP-System as far as my PC can handle, and I came up with nothing. I tried a small group of order $3^n,n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. I tried this code in GAP:

```
for n in [1..10] do
  for j in [1..NrSmallGroups(3^n)] do
    G:=SmallGroup(3^n,j);
    if NilpotencyClassOfGroup(G)=3 then
      if Length(GeneratorsOfGroup(G))=3 then
        Print(n,", ",j,"\n");
      fi;
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

Comment: what is a group of class 3?

Comment: what do you mean with three generators? you want it to be cyclic?

Comment: i want it to be like $G=<x,y,z>$

Comment: Oh ok I see. And you also don't wan't it to be $<x,y>$ right?

Comment: What have you tried in GAP? You should be able to find an example of order $3^5$. Also, do you need a 3-group, or a $p$-group for other $p$ that you've tried?

Comment: i tried $3^5$ didn't get result

Comment: Thanks for the GAP code - now it's immediately clear that the problem is in the wrong use of `GeneratorsOfGroup` as @ahulpke explained in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is your formulation and test of "with three generators". Presumably you mean that the group can be generated by 3 elements (but not by 2). Of course you could generate such a group with more elements.
The generating set stored by GAP and returned by `GeneratorsOfGroup` is for solvable groups a polycyclic generating set, which for a group of order $p^n$ has always $n$ generators. Thus your test eliminates all groups.

If you replace `Length(GeneratorsOfGroup(G))` by `Length(MinimalGeneratingSet(G))` you will find the groups you're interested in (starting in order $3^5$ as noted by Alexander Konovalov above.)

Comment: Just to add that one-liner to find one such group in GAP is `G:=OneSmallGroup(Size,3^5,NilpotencyClassOfGroup,3,g->Size(MinimalGeneratingSet(g)),3);`. If you need more groups, use `AllSmallGroups` or the loop as in the original question if you want to control the progress of calculation.